# How to add member function for built-in types such as integer in C++

Tags: c++, function, built-in

I'm implementing something by using C++, I have a cluster of type index, it includes two members: one is an integer, the other is a struct, like this:

```
typedef int IndexA_t;
struct IndexB_t { ... };
```

Here comes a requirement, I want to add a common function (suppose, name it fun1()) for these two types as I want to pass them in a template function which will call fun1(), it's easy to achieve this for *IndexB_t*, but it puzzles me for *IndexA_t*, how can I introduce a function member for an integer (built-in) type? Shall I have to implement a class simulating int type? it really needs lots of unnecessary work (many operators...), is there any other way?

Very appreciated for your help, thanks.

Comment: You can't. You could, however, make `fun1()` a free-standing function that takes its parameter and does the necessary work. Similar to how [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) is a free-standing function that takes the container as an argument, and then will delegate to `.begin()` on that container if it can (for e.g. `std::vector`), or delegate to something else that can return the correct value (for e.g. an array like `int [5]` which has no `.begin()`).

Comment: How to decide if an container can or cannot invoke .beign(), by template specialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do as cornstalks suggests and use the same technique employed by `std::begin` and `std::end`. It provides overloads for objects that define `begin`/`end` member functions and provides overloads for further types (in that case arrays) which it makes sense to use the function on.

In the below contrived example, we have a `getval` free function, which provides overloads for types that define a `getval` member function, using the trailing return type to activate SFINAE. Then for other types it uses type traits to ensure that only types which are integers are allowed and all others rejected, again using SFINAE via `enable_if`.

This example is **contrived** and is only intended to show the technique, which you can employ to implement whichever functionality you require (the question does not elaborate what that is, so I had to use license). It would clearly be easier in the below case to achieve the same effect by adding an int conversion operator to the `IndexB_t` class, but that's not the point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

/* is_integer type trait */
template<typename T>
using is_integer = is_same<remove_cv_t<T>, int>;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_integer_v = is_integer<T>::value;

/* getval function definition */
template<typename T, 
         typename = enable_if_t<is_integer_v<T>>
        >
T getval(T i)
{ return i; }

template<typename T>
auto getval(T& t) -> decltype(t.getval())
{ return t.getval(); }

/* defined types */
typedef int IndexA_t;

class IndexB_t 
{ 
    int x;

    public:
    IndexB_t(int i) : x(i) {}

    int getval() const { return x; }
};

// a test struct with no `getval` member function.
struct NoGetVal {};

// driver function
int main()
{
    int i = 9;
    IndexB_t j = 10;
    IndexA_t k = 11;
    const int l = 12;
    volatile int m = 13;
    const volatile int n = 14;
    float a = 1.1;
    NoGetVal ngv;

    cout << getval(i) << '\n';
    cout << getval(j) << '\n';
    cout << getval(k) << '\n';
    cout << getval(l) << '\n';
    cout << getval(m) << '\n';
    cout << getval(n) << '\n';

    // disallowed as not int
    //cout << getval(a) << '\n';

    // disallowed no `getval` member function
    //cout << getval(ngv) << '\n';
}
```

So now you have a consistent interface for integer primitives and objects that act like integers.

You may want to lessen the restriction on which types are allowed in the primitive type overload, perhaps using `std::is_integral`. It's up to you.

This is c++14 but could be stepped down to c++11 by using `enable_if` instead of `enable_if_t` et al. and adapting the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too hard implement a type which behaves like `int` but can be extended.

```
#include <iostream>

class Int
{
  int m_i;
public:
  Int(int i) : m_i(i) {};
  operator int&() { return m_i; }
  operator int() const { return m_i; }
};

void func(int) {}

int main()
{
  // copy-assignment from int
  Int i = 2;
  i = 4+15;

  // Binding reference
  int& x = i;
  x = 2;

  // Implicit conversion in expression
  std::cout << i + 2 << '\n';

  // Implicit conversion in parameter
  func(i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It's possible, but I wonder if any other way, I really do not want to maintain a self-defined Int class. :(